# Conditionalizing routes with the resolve in angularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to change a current route depending on screen width in angular. My resolve function runs before the UI renders, and I can determine whether or not I want to display a mobile variant of the screen or not.

```
when "/messages/:id",
  templateUrl: "../templates/messages/show.html"
  controller: "MessageCtrl"
  resolve:
    route: ["$location", "Device", "$routeParams", ($location, Device, $routeParams) ->
      console.log($routeParams)
      if Device.screenWideEnough(768)
        console.log "wide enough"
        $location.path "/bigMessageScreen"
        # $location.path("/bigMessagesScreen").search({messageId : $routeParams.id})
    ]
```

However, I'm not sure how to retrieve the `id` parameter from the route from within the resolve function. I've injected $routeParams but am returned an empty object when I examine it.

What is the "angular way" to do this? This feels pretty hacky but I need to retrieve the value of the parameter so I can generate the new route correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `$route` service seems to have the params referenced by the future route, even though `$routeParams` does not. The following code functions correctly:

```
resolve:
    route: ["$location", "Device", "$route", ($location, Device, $route) ->
      if Device.screenWideEnough(768)
        $location.path("/messages").search({id : $route.current.params.id})
    ]
```